# Flexible eCommerce and social networking solution

Tags: php, e-commerce, social-networking

Im currently developing website that will contain e-commerce part and social networking part.
Social networking part might have following options:

- Users

  - Edit profile
  - Upload photos / videos
  - Manage friends
  - Select favorite product (+review)
- Groups
- Forums
- Videos
- Photos

So, basically it is a merge of regular ecommerce store and social elements. And what im trying to do: find flexible CMS that can provide such features. I don't really know which one to choose, because it is really complex project. But i need to find the best matching solution.

Can anyone who had succeed with something like that recommend CMS for this project? 
Language: PHP

**Update:**
Primary part of the projects is eCommerce. After integrating the store i will do social network.

I checked out Drupal system, it is quite powerful for such stuff. Tons of modules.

Answer (score 0):

[Elgg](http://elgg.org/index.php) is one of the best open source social networking engine.. you can try the link..